# Mysql Update Case Query

Tags: mysql

can't get what's wrong with this query

I'm getting error at the first SET and I don't understand what I am missing...

```
UPDATE 
supplier t1,
ps_product t2,
ps_product_shop t3,
SET t2.price=CASE
    WHEN t1.prezzo<=4.99 THEN 
    t1.prezzo*2
    END,
t2.wholesale_price=CASE
    WHEN t1.prezzo<=4.99 THEN t1.prezzo*2
    END,
t3.price=CASE
    WHEN t1.prezzo<=4.99 THEN t1.prezzo*2
    END,
t3.wholesale_price=CASE
    WHEN t1.prezzo<=4.99 THEN t1.prezzo*2
    END
WHERE 
t1.code=t2.reference
AND 
t2.id_product=t3.id_product
AND 
t2.id_product=t4.id_product
```

Comment: use parenthesis before `CASE` and after `END`

Comment: Like this? it's not working SET t2.price=(CASE
  WHEN t1.prezzo<=4.99 THEN t1.prezzo*2
  END)

Comment: yes.. it should be like that

Comment: it still gives me error...

Comment: remove commas before first `SET` then add parenthesis before *CASE* and after *END*.

Comment: yes, it was the comma after t3 (4th row). Thank you! :)

Comment: Add an answer to this question and mark it as right answer. To make sure that your question has been answered. It's ok, to answer your own question. :)

Answer (score -1):

As RubahMalam suggested it was the comma before the first SET

Comment: use comment for this